# Drupal 7 and File Upload error

Tags: files

I get the following error after uploading a file (using FileField in CCK):
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2171 of /srv/bindings/ee146cfb80a24c269f208052b67f5634/code/includes/database/database.inc).

Any hints on how to fix? The file module 7.30 is used.

Comment: If it's Drupal 7, then it's no longer a CCK. Or you have a version mismatch?

Comment: Using File and Field version 7.30

Comment: Have you executed update.php after last update? And purged all caches?

Comment: yes I have run update.php and cleared the cache